# How do I add a search function to array?

Tags: c++

I need to add a function to search in the string array and bring up the user with associated phone number. Though Im lost. Any functions created only bring up the persons name without the number. If not found, it needs to say error.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i, n, j;
    string name[100];
    string phone[100];
    int index[100];

    cout << "How many names and phone numbers do you want to enter? " << endl
         << "Entering 0 ends the program." << endl;
    cin >> n;

    if (n == 0)
        return 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        cout << "Please enter a name: ";
        cin >> name[i];

        cout << "Please enter a phone number: ";
        cin >> phone[i];
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        index[i] = i;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            int temp;
            if (phone[index[i]] > phone[index[j]]) {
                temp = index[i];
                index[i] = index[j];
                index[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "These entries are in ascending order by phone number: " << endl;
    cout << "Name"
         << "            "
         << "Phone Number" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        cout << name[index[i]] << "              " << phone[index[i]] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of having parallel arrays you really should consider using a class/struct to bind the phone number and name together.  Then you can have a single array of those records.  Makes this stuff much easier to deal with.

Comment: If the user enters a number greater than 100 for the desired amount of phone numbers, the array will be overflowed leading to undefined behavior.

Comment: it must use parallel arrays, its a requirement.

Comment: why you are using a separate index array, just swap the user names along with phone numbers while sorting.

Comment: @RajeevSingh Because that is a lot less expensive then sorting strings.  It is a cleaver trick when dealing with sorting very large objects or multiple arrays without modifying all of them.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes with a cost of space

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code should work for you (if i understood the question)

```
 int search(string name[], string searchedName){
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
            if(searchedName == name[i])
                return i;   //Returns the position of the person, which is also the index of his phone number
        }
        return -1;   //If -1 is returned it means there is no such name an "searchedName" in the vector
    }
```

You can call this function like this

```
int main(){
      /* all the stuff you already have inside here */
    string nameToSearch;
    cout<<"Insert the name of the person you want to see the number of"<<endl;
    cin>>nameToSearch;
    int position = search(name, nameToSearch);
    if(position == -1)
       cout<<"Sorry, "<<nameToSearch<<" is not in our list"<<endl;
    else
      cout<<"The phone number of "<<nameToSearch<<" is "<<phone[position]<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Of course this is pretty basic and you can make it better, hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you Emanuele, this is what I needed. I'm still learning, and the examples provided by my instructor are terrible.

Comment: No problems if you have any trouble feel free to ask other questions

Comment: You are downvoting this just becouse you are like "oh he should use a struct he should use a class" but probably you don't get that this guy just started with c++ and probably with programming in general. Instead of downvoting this post your solutions

Comment: Or also that the "100" limitation will cause errors. I know that it will overflow but where is the problem if this guy is just trying to do what his teacher said? Maybe programming in his class is just not important as others (i have a friend who does 2 hours at week of programming and she really doesn't care at all the things a real programmer worries about, she does what the teacher says and nothing more, also with parallel arrays)